# Customer not marked as notified programatically Magento

Tags: email, magento, notifications, history

> add a one new batch action in magento , in this i am changing the
>   status of the order pragmatically

.Its all working fine

> but the problem is after changing the status and send email to
>   customer also it is not showing customer notified in comment history

. Below is the code

```
$order->setIsCustomerNotified(false);
$order->setStatus("ready_for_pickup");
$order->addStatusHistoryComment($comment, false);
$order->save();
$order->sendOrderUpdateEmail($notify = true, $comment);
```

Can you please suggest me how can i fix this.

thanks

Answer (score 3):

OK i have got the solution and by below piece of code it is working fine now.

```
$order->setIsCustomerNotified(false);
$order->setStatus("your_order_status");
$historyItem = $order->addStatusHistoryComment($comment, "your_order_status");
$historyItem->setIsCustomerNotified(1)->save();
$order->save();
$order->sendOrderUpdateEmail($notify = true, $comment);
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also send order update email just using sendOrderUpdateEmail. After order save.

```
$order->save();
$order->sendOrderUpdateEmail($notify = true, 'Replace your comment');
```